# What exactly is the Leibnitz rule in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

In the Differential Geometry part of a course in General Relativity (for instance in David Tong's notes [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr.html) in page 99, accessed 21 Nov, 2019), one frequently comes across the Leibnitz rule when defining some differential operators like the covariant derivative or a tangent vector.

Take the covariant derivative, as an example, we have the following *definition* of Leibnitz rule:

$$
\nabla_X (fY) = f \nabla_X (Y) + (\nabla_Xf)Y
$$

which is all well and good. However, later in the course (see page 102 of [Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr.html)), Leibnitz rule is used as follows:

$$
\nabla _ { X } ( \omega ( Y ) ) = \left( \nabla _ { X } \omega \right) ( Y ) + \omega \left( \nabla _ { X } Y \right) 
$$

where $\omega \in \Lambda^1(M) $ is a one-form and $X, Y$ are vector fields.

Now even though the two may seem to be compatible, $\omega(Y)$ is a function **composition** and not a simple *multiplication* as defined in the first equation. Thus, how does the definition above actually give us the result as shown in the second equation? Or is the definition for simple multiplication simply *not* general enough to give us the result we want in equation 2? In that case why do we see the above definition almost everywhere?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Just write your equation in index notation and it will seem perfectly natural to use the product rule, because you are differentiating a product.

Comment: @Qmechanic That is a good point but I feel that the Mathematics site usually gets pure Maths answers that go beyond the level of differential geometry taught by a GR course in undergrad Physics.

Comment: @G.Smith I tried doing that but I can't get the correct Christoffel symbols that way: $\nabla_X(\omega_j Y^j) = \nabla_X(\omega_j)Y^j + \omega_j\nabla_X(Y^j) = X(\omega_j)Y^j + \omega_j X(Y^j)$

Comment: You are right, the first version of the Leibniz rule is not enough to deduce the second version from it. $\nabla_X \omega$ is simply apriori not defined. To extend the covariant derivative to one-forms, one usually uses precisely your second equation. (Together with the requirement that $\nabla_X f = \mathrm{d}f (X)$ for any function $f \in C^\infty(M)$). You can, along the same line of thought, define the covariant derivative of tensor fields of arbitrary rank by requiring a more general Leibniz rule: $\nabla_X(S \otimes T) = \nabla_X(S) \otimes T + S \otimes \nabla_X(T)$.

Comment: (Additionally requiring that $\nabla_X$ commutes with contractions, if I recall correctly...)

Comment: $\omega(Y)(p) = \omega_pY_p$ for any $p \in M$ with $M$ the manifold. This means that $\omega(Y) \in C^\infty(M)$